# Why am I automatically logged in to my Stack Overflow account?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, login, logout

Why is it my Stack Overflow account is automatically logged in? Even though I log out. What should I do to prevent from logging in automatically?

Comment: May be because you are logged-in in [your network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/2154850/portgas-d-ace). Try to logout from there.

Comment: If you're using Google as your OpenID provider then if you are logged in to Google (e.g. gmail, YouTube) then  you're also logged in any site you're using that same Google account. That's from my own experience, though guess it's the same for the other providers as well..

Comment: @portgas d ace - please change `Stack Ooverflow` to `Stack Overflow`

Comment: @Ty221 That's a different question. This question is asking *not* to be logged in automatically.

Answer (score 2):

**This isn't a bug.**

If you are logged-in [here](https://stackexchange.com/), the system will log you in automatically. Try logging out there and check again.